# Did HBO change the title of Game of Thrones S07E06?

Tags: game-of-thrones, title

*Game of Thrones S07E06* was leaked, and we've seen questions titling the episode *Death is the Enemy* - and that phrase is actually uttered by one of the characters in the episode.

Yet when the episode actually aired, it did so as *Beyond the Wall*.

Did HBO change the title at the last minute? Why? What gives?

Comment: The episode was leaked by HBO Spain, so there's a related question of whether episodes have the same title in all languages.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the episode was in english

Comment: @Mart10 I'd assume that HBO Spain is intended primarily for viewers located in Spain, at least some of whom may not understand English, so there are likely (optional) Spanish subtitles available, as well as potentially an episode synopsis - also in Spanish - that the title could be taken from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, HBO didn't change the title. Even title *Death is the Enemy* is not the official title, *Beyond the Walls* is.

From [this source](http://decider.com/2017/08/14/game-of-thrones-season-7-episode-6-preview/) (might contain spoilers)

> This week’s official Game of Thrones preview. As of publication, HBO still hadn’t released an official name for the episode. UPDATE! **The official title is “Beyond the Wall.”**

From the same page,

> We open north of the Wall. Ser Beric says in voice over: “Death is the enemy.”

This is what might have made fans think that the title is *Death is the Enemy*.

Other sources such as [UPROXX](http://uproxx.com/tv/new-game-of-thrones-photos-episode-6-beyond-the-wall-season-7/) also says the same.

Here is the [official tweet](https://twitter.com/GameOfThrones/status/899285417157054464).

> Tonight.
>       “Beyond the Wall” premieres at 9PM on @HBO. #GoTS7 pic.twitter.com/wMYagT02Pb
>       — Game Of Thrones (@GameOfThrones) August 20, 2017

Comment: Just got back home... Kinda flabbergasted right now, my digital recorder has S7E6 titled "Death is the Enemy"